# Password verifier problems

Tags: java, string

I am trying to complete my programming assignment, I have to create a "Password verifier" that has 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 1 number, and 1 special character.  If invalid, it must show "invalid" plus the rule that it has shown as false.  The problem I have, is not an error message, but I always get a positive response, plus all the violated rules, plus it reads them twice.  Little help here?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PasswordVerifier {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Password Verifier");
        System.out.println("Enter a password that meets the following rules: ");
        System.out.println("-Must be at least 8 characters long" + '\n' +
                "-Must contain at least 1 lower case character" + '\n' +
                "-Must contain at least 1 upper case character" + '\n' +
                "-Must contain at least 1 numeric digit" + '\n' +
                "-Must contain at least 1 special character from the set: !@#$%^&*" + '\n' +
                "-Must not contain the word 'and' or the word 'end'");

        String password;
        String contains1 = "and";
        String contains2 = "end";
        String special = "!@#$%^&*";

        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean digit = false;        //Has at least 1 digit
        boolean upper = true;        //Has at least 1 upper case letter
        boolean lower = true;        //Has at least 1 lower case letter
        boolean hasspecial = true;    //Has at least 1 special character
        boolean length = true;        //Has at least 8 digits
        boolean endand = true;        //Does not contain end or and
        boolean valid = false;        //Is the password valid?


        System.out.println("Enter password: ");
        password = stdIn.nextLine();


        int result;
        result = password.indexOf(contains1);
        if (result == -1) {
            System.out.println("");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Must not contain the word 'and'");
        }

        int result2;
        result2 = password.indexOf(contains2);
        if (result2 == -1) {
            System.out.println("");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Must not contain the word 'end'");
        }

        if (password.length() < 8) {
            System.out.println("Must be at least 8 characters long.");
        } else {
            System.out.print("");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
            if (!(Character.isUpperCase(password.charAt(i)))) ;
            {
                upper = false;
                valid = false;
                i++;
            }
            if (!(Character.isLowerCase(password.charAt(i)))) ;
            {
                lower = false;
                valid = false;
                i++;
            }
            if (!(Character.isDigit(password.charAt(i)))) ;
            {
                digit = false;
                valid = false;
                i++;
            }
            if (!(password.matches(special))) ;
            {
                hasspecial = false;
                valid = false;
            }

            if (upper != true) {
                System.out.println("Must contain an upper case letter.");
            }
            if (lower != true) {
                System.out.println("Must contain a lower case letter.");
            }
            if (digit != true) {
                System.out.println("Must contain a numeric digit.");
            }
            if (hasspecial != true) {
                System.out.println("Must contain a special character.");
            }
            if (valid) {
                System.out.println("Valid.");
            } else if (valid != true) {
                System.out.println("Invalid.");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Pick a password, and execute your algorithm on paper, noting the value of each variable at each step. Just a hint: the fact that you have found a character that is not uppercase doesn't mean that the password doesn't have any uppercase character.

Comment: You never assign **true** to **valid** variable.So how can you get positive response??

Comment: So I changed the "valid" to "true" but I am getting the same problems...

Comment: Nm rewrote in a diff format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing. All your if lines are wrong.

You are adding a ';' after the if. That means, if the if condition is met, do nothing, then always execute the following lines.

Another thing, when you do

```
if (!(password.matches(special))) {
   hasspecial = false;
   valid = false;
}
```

You are asking for the password to match the string "!@#$%^&(asterisk)", which it probably doesn't. So, since you are assuming that the string contains a special character, hasspecial will always be true. You want to write something like password.matches(".(asterisk)[!@#$%^&*].(asterisk)) (Probably escaping some characters).

Finally, you are saying if a letter doesn't meet a condition, set the marker to false. So, if the following letter does meet the condition, the marker will still be false. You should usually approach this kind of problems by assuming that all of the conditions are false and then setting the markers to true once the condition is met.

Note: I wrote (asterisk) instead of *, becasue the text gets highlighted and I don't know how to escape it :(